# Disable a Route with Kong API Gateway

Tags: api-gateway, kong, kong-plugin

We have a service pointing to the backend in the Kong API Gateway. And each service has multiple routes associated with it.

I would like to disable/enable individual Routes in Production. Looking at the Admin API documentation, 'Update Route' API does not have any property to disable/enable the route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Received an answer on konghq:
https://discuss.konghq.com/t/disable-a-route-with-kong-api-gateway/3735/2